# 2 ways of every 5 minutes time format in crontab

Tags: cron

Good day,

As I know, there are 2 ways to write the time format of every 5 minutes in `crontab`. The following is my example:

Example 1:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Example 2:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

I can successful using the second example, however, I hit error when I using Example 1:
`crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.`

Not understand actually what is the cause, suppose it should be correct.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Maybe you are on Solaris? As far as I know - in this case - the former synthax is not recognized, and you have to specify every minute, as in your second example.

Comment: The syntax is fine and working well to me. Wouldn't you happen to have some trailing errors in previous lines?